# Flutter app is suspended on windows when run

Tags: flutter, windows

I'm trying to run an App in Flutter on Windows .
The strange problem is that the app is perfectly running on my Windows pc where I coded it, but when I pick the app (I pick the whole build directory!) and try to run on the target Windows pc, the OS suspends and kills it. I'm not an expert on windows, I opened the event registry and it tells me "id EVENT 1005", with no more info.  I am sure it finds all .dlls, because all it needs is on the release folder. To build the app I've made:

```
flutter deploy windows --release.
```

Moreover on other windows systems my app runs . So, my question is about windows: how and when Windows suspends a flutter process (I can run open source applications without problems)?